# XML - XSLT - number and sort

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to sort my xml data and also number them. Here is for example xml code:

```
  <images>
      <image>
        <title>cat</title>
        <grade>3</grade>
      </image>
      <image>
        <title>dog</title>
        <grade>5</grade>
      </image>
      <image>
        <title>snake</title>
        <grade>1</grade>
      </image>
      <image>
        <title>fish</title>
        <grade>2</grade>
      </image>
   </images>
```

and xslt code:

```
  <xsl:template match="images">
    <xsl:for-each select="image">
      <xsl:sort select="grade"/>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <xsl:number/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="grade"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

The result of this is:

```
3 cat  1
4 fish 2
1 cat  3
2 dog  5
```

And i would like to have:

```
1 cat  1
2 fish 2
3 cat  3
4 dog  5
```

How can I make this in a simple way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `<xsl:number />` do this instead

```
 <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
```

`position()` will return the position of the node in the selected node-set after it has been sorted (as opposed to the position of the node in the hierarchy).

Answer (score 1):

xsl:number is good, but you need the current position. Also you should sort by numeric value:

```
<xsl:template match="images">
    <xsl:for-each select="image">
      <xsl:sort select="number(grade)"/>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <xsl:number value="position()"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="grade"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: `<xsl:sort select="number(grade)"/>` That would work in XSLT 2.0, but not in XSLT 1.0. `<xsl:sort select="grade" data-type="number"/>` would work for both.